# click() in javascript doesn't work but in console it works fine

Tags: javascript

I want to play a music from soundcloud in my website and it doesn't autoplay in Chrome. 
so to resolve this problem i decided to auto click on a play and pause button when page load.
but i have a new problem now and the click() is not working :(

here's the code:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  console.log("a");
  document.getElementById("play").click();
}, 1000);
```

```html
    <section id="audioW">
        <a href="#" id="play" onload="autoclick('#play')"><img src="https://saeedrezvanian.com/wp-content/themes/saeedrezvanian/img/play.svg" alt="control" id="control"></a>
        <a href="https://soundcloud.com/barfakmusic" target="_blank" id="audio">Barfak</a>
    </section>
```

"a" showed up in console fine but the play button never clicked

I hope somebody can help me

Comment: Well is the button there?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML you are using ?

Comment: What is the id or class name of the iframe that sound cloud loads?

Comment: Please post the HTML

Comment: You can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to create a runnable example (a [mcve]) here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: try to replace `console.log("a")` with `console.log(document.getElementById("play"))` and provide us the result. If it's `null`, it's likely the HTML tag doesn't present at the time Javascript code is executed.

Comment: Did you get any errors in the console?

Comment: @epascarello yes

Comment: @SanyamGoel I added it

Comment: @osmanraifgunes It's not a iframe i added html

Comment: So why are you not just calling `autoclick('#play')`

Comment: @SimonRi I added it

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze might want to recheck that

Comment: @blaz I did it and console return the a tag

Comment: @FZs yes and it related to chrome banned auto play 
Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Comment: @kevinSpaceyIsKeyserSöze `click()` (used on a jQuery Object) is a part of jQuery, but if used on a DOM node, it has a different behaviour. [Read this!](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_html_click.asp)

Comment: Tried  document.getElementById("myAudio").autoplay=true?
But I think this is the chrome browser preventing it.
Try it in firefox or edge with the above.

Comment: document.getElementById("audio").click(); is the correct one to refer. btw it will just open a new window of the website for you not play

Answer (score 0):

Retoric question: Why would they set up this limitation on `autoplay` attribute and `HTMLMediaElement.play()` method if all that were needed was an `HTMLElement.click()`?

You need an [USER-gesture](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#triggered-by-user-activation).

---

To your click issue that looks like a typo: `onload` => `onclick`

Comment: I wanna auto click on "a" tag called "#play" when page load and I dont get your advice :(

Comment: You want to do it so that the audio plays automatically right? A kind of a workaround for Chrome's new policies against autoplaying sounds? Then that won't work. And if you want something to fire on page load then it's on the body's onload that you should hook in markup (even though you shouldn't hook in markup)